# Rails 3.1 associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Rails 3.1.1 application with the following models:

```
Company
Member
```

The two models have the following associations:

```
Company - has_many :members
Member  - belongs_to :company
```

When adding members I can enter the company ID number and the record is linked successfully, I can lookup members through the company etc.

When I am working on the member show view I would like to 'pull' in details of the company.

Currently I have the following in the show view:

```
<h1>Listing members</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Mobile</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Qualifications</th>
    <th>Membership</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @members.each do |member| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= member.name %></td>
    <td><%= member.mobile %></td>
    <td><%= member.email %></td>
    <td><%= member.qualifications %></td>
    <td><%= member.membership %></td>
    <td><%= @member.company.company_id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', member %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_member_path(member) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', member, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

How do I go about pulling in a field from the related company? For example the company model has two fields (latitude and longitude).

Comment: There's something I don't understand here, wouldn't `<%= member.company.latitude %>` work?

Comment: That results in 'undefined local variable or method `member' for #<#<Class:0x99cdcc8>:0x99a8a40>'

Comment: did you put it in the members loop (right below `<%= member.membership %>` for example)?

Comment: Ahh..that works if it's placed within the members list block. Thanks! Is it possible to make it a link?

Comment: @danymcc a link to what? A link to a latitude doesn't make much sense, maybe you're talking about the company itself?

Comment: @dannymcc StackOverflow is for troubleshooting or solving specific errors. You're asking us some very basic questions that could be (and should be) answered by reading some beginning Rails tutorials. I recommend [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/).

Comment: Sorry, yeah if I change your suggestion to <%= member.company.name %> how do you make that link to the company record? <%= link_to '??', member.company %>?

Comment: I know, I tried the method that I thought would work and didn't understand why it didn't. That's where StackOverflow has always come in useful. If I hadn't have tried to do it myself first then I would agree that the question shouldn't be here.

Comment: @dannymcc you're asking without trying it first.

Comment: Regarding the link_to or the initial question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop should look like this:

```
<% @members.each do |member| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= member.name %></td>
    <td><%= member.mobile %></td>
    <td><%= member.email %></td>
    <td><%= member.qualifications %></td>
    <td><%= member.membership %></td>
    <td><%= member.company_id %></td>
    <td><%= member.company.latitude %></td>
    <td><%= link_to member.company.name, member.company %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', member %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_member_path(member) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', member, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

`company_id` is defined on the `Member` model, you cannot access it through `member.company.company_id`. To access a field on the related company model, use `member.company.my_field`.

These will only work in the members loop, as they access the `|member|` variable which is passed to the block.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Worked perfectly. I don't understand why in the link to you don't wrap the link name with ''? Is that only when you want static elements? For example; <%= link_to 'Company', member.company %>

Comment: @dannymcc Yes, you got this right. You don't put quotes when getting the link name from a model attribute or a variable, only when passing a hardcoded string.

Answer (score 0):

```
@member.company.latitude
```

et cetera. Please let me know if you want clarification or more information.

Comment: I seem to get an error for that 'undefined method `company' for nil:NilClass'

Comment: It should be `member` if you're using it within the loop in your example. And your next error will be `undefined method 'company_id' for Company....`, and to solve that you need to change this line: `@member.company.company_id` to something else or remove it. Then go read some [Ruby/Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)... this is basic stuff.